# FirebaseRemoteConfig fetchAndActivate not updating new value

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

I have already set the minimum interval to be 0 when in Debug mode.
Currently what I do to fetch new data is by clearing the app storage first before launching the app.

Here is my code:

```
private fun initRemoteConfig() {
    remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
    configSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) 0 else 3600)
        .build()
    remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults)
    fetch()
}

private fun fetch() {
    remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val updated = it.result
                Logger.d(TAG, "Config params updated: $updated. Fetch and activate succeeded") // updated = false

                checkVersion()
            } else {
                Logger.d(TAG, "Fetch failed")
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
private fun initRemoteConfig() {
  remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
  configSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
    .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) 0 else 3600)
    .build()
  remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)  //You missed this line
  remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults)
  fetch()
}

private fun fetch() {
  remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val updated = task.result
            Logger.d(TAG, "Config params updated: $updated. Fetch and activate succeeded") // updated = false
            checkVersion()
        } else {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Fetch failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will try to shed some light on why replacing `fetchAndActivate` with `fetch` and `activate` works.

The reason is the caching of remote config behind the `fetchAndActivate` function. It caches the new data for an amount of time. That time defaults to -1 which possibly means forever (not sure about that though, could mean 1 day, or something along those lines).

When the data is already cached, it doesn't even try to fetch them again. Therefore it seems, as if it isn't working.
When you call `fetch(0)` it sets caching time to 0 seconds.

That is the reason why it will fetch new remote config values every time.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. calling `fetch()` with no arguments is equivalent to passing the `minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds` as the argument. You can check the code for that (the override is in class `ConfigFetchHandler`). I think @VVB has the correct answer here, which is simply that OP missed to actually apply the `configSettings` object created

Answer (score 2):

I changed my code from `fetchAndActivate` to `fetch` and it seems to be working as expected. I am now getting new data from the Firebase.

Here is my updated code:

```
private fun fetch() {
    val fetch = remoteConfig.fetch(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) 0 else TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(12))
    fetch.addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            remoteConfig.activate()
            Logger.d(TAG, "Fetch and activate succeeded")

            checkVersion()
        } else {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Fetch failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the early stages of development, there is a method that can be used to test. It worked for me. It would be helpful if you refer to the code and Google Doc below.

For your information, you can estimate the time you have communicated with the server through 'remoteConfig.lastFetchTime'.

```
final remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
await remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
    fetchTimeout: const Duration(minutes: 1),
    minimumFetchInterval: const Duration(minutes: 5),
));
```

> During app development, if you're not using real-time Remote Config (which we recommend), you might want to fetch and activate configs very frequently (many times per hour) to let you rapidly iterate as you develop and test your app. To accommodate rapid iteration on a project with up to 10 developers, you can temporarily set a low minimum fetch interval with setConfigSettings().

link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=flutter#fetch-values

Answer (score 0):

The default remote update is 43200000 ms which are 720 minutes or 12 hours.
It is recommended use the default.

If u wish to debug or use a new value u can set the

```
remoteConfig.settings.minimumFetchIntervalMillis = 5000
```

Debug your app and then remove it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it calling the onConfigUpdated function before the fetchAndActivate, as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=flutter&hl=es-419#add-real-time-listener) suggests on step 7:

```
await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();

remoteConfig.onConfigUpdated.listen((event) async {
   print('### Remote Config Updated');
   await remoteConfig.activate();
});
```

Hope It helps someone :)